# What exactly is the default Javascript VM environment in Remix?

Tags: remix

When using the online Remix IDE, the `Run` tab has default values of `Environment="JavaScript VM"` and `Account=<a list of addresses I don't own that already have 100 ether each>`. What exactly is this environment? Is it a private (test) network that gets set up each time I refresh the browser (which would explain how it seems to be able to simply give me ether to play with) or something else?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run_tab.html), for the JavaScript VM environment:

> transactions will be executed in **a sandbox blockchain in the browser**.
>   This means nothing will be persisted and a page reload will restart a
>   new blockchain from scratch, the old one will not be saved.

So, yes, Remix uses a private blockchain and accounts by default that you can use for testing.

Comment: Any idea on how to query that blockchain for things like current block number?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so here's an updated link to the [docs](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run.html) mentioned above.

> For connecting to a sandbox blockchain in the browser. The Remix VM (previously called JavaScript VM) is its own “blockchain” and on each reload the old chain will be cleared and a new blockchain will be started. The old one will not be saved. The London refers to the London fork of Ethereum.